# Edit data from a listbox to my SQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, insert-update

Table name: highscores

Whenever I want to edit a selected registration (with gamer and hscore properties), my gamer value turns into "0" and the highscore remains unchanged.

For example, I've entered a user: Andrew with 332 highscore points and I want to edit into Zack with 009 highscore points, turns into 0 and the highscore remains 332 (previous highscore registration)

The program's main task is to insert, edit, and delete data from a Listbox to the MySQL database.

This is my original method:

```
public static void edit(Highscore hs)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = DBConnection.getConnection();

        if (con == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Conexiunea la baza de date nu s-a realizat.");
        }

        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE highscores SET gamer=@gamer,highscore=@hscore WHERE id=@id ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamer", hs.Gamer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hscore", hs.Hscore);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", hs.Id);



        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Editarea nu s-a putut face.");
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

and i want to call the method into the Main class:

```
 private void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDiag = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca doriti sa editati aceasta inregistrare?", "EDITEAZA", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);



        if (resDiag == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            Highscore hs = listBox1.SelectedItem as Highscore;
            HighscoresDAO.edit(hs);


            button1_Click(this, null);



        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I assume when you say that " it will change into 0 and the highscore remains 332, from the previous one." that you are checking the results in your mySQL table? Have you checked that the values you are passing in as parameters have the correct value?

Comment: do you reffer to button1_Click(this,null) from the main class?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I forgot to give proper parameters.